# How to Optimize django application for images and static files

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, optimization, django-3.0

I'm building a website using Django(3) in which we have implemented `blogs` to post articles on the site. For each blog post, we have to add `images` one feature image and the other may need to be used within the post. You can find the site at: https://pythonist.org

I can see in google console my website is too slow due to images and static css/js files.
I'm compressing the image on uploading using the code below:

```
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, max_length=120)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    featured_image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='course_images/', format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 80}, blank=False)
```

I'm using `safe` to load template variables and utilize `cache`, `prefetch_selected`, and other basic optimization tweaks.

> But are there other practical ways to load my images and static files
> faster?

My site has been deployed on Heroku.

Comment: I may be overlooking some logic, but isn't the general advice, also given in the Django documentation, that images should be served through a (separate) webserver, not through Django? A webserver will also likely automatically compress and cache images for you (with the right settings).

Comment: You should clarify if the slow part is about uploading (which only happens once per blog post, so really shouldn't matter), or about loading (which happens per view, so multiple times per second/minute/day/year).

Comment: I dont know If its true that your static files are the problem. I looked at your website and it has some big images but nothing crazy. You could try to aim for 250kb max per img and decrease the amount of images in total but this wont bring your loading time much down. Did you check for duplicated queries? Maybe the template engine in doing a bunch of extra SQL statements? Check https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar or django silk. Aim for 10 (or less) requests per site. If nothing helps start loading parts of that website async with XHR.

Comment: Normally Django does *not* serve images/files in production. Normally that is done through the webserver like *apache* or *nginx* and these can be optiimized to cache images, and send data in a compressed way.

Comment: @9769953 he is using s3

Comment: @9769953 It's about the slow loading in the browser, not the image uploading.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Chome lighthouse, I have noticed 8 unique images, with 4.5 MB in total! They are highlighted in red here, basically your thumbnails are full sized hero-images taken from the other blog posts. [image: Blog Thumbnails]
Create thumbnails programmatically whenever an image gets uploaded. Your thumbnail boxes have a width of 80x80 px. As far as I know, doubling the target size is good for most displays (because of dpi / pixel density I think), correct me if I'm wrong.

With imagekit it looks easy to do that. Add another field to keep the thumbnail and the blog page will end up with 7 160x160 px images and one full size image instead. I would even use a cap resolution on the header, just in case.

```
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField, ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit # or try ResizeToFill

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, max_length=120)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    featured_image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='course_images/', format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 80}, blank=False)
    # in your template thumbnails, use this image instead
    featured_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='featured_image',
                                  processors=[ResizeToFit(160, 160)],
                                  format='JPEG',
                                  options={'quality': 70})
```

I don't think there's performance you can get out from compressing your css and js files, but you can do that if your css/js assets increase.
Each request to the server adds a bit of an overhead to fetch the data, also it's a good practice to only use 1-2 servers or CDNs for all static files, which you already do.

You can read about **inlining the above-the-fold-content css** and **defer loading**, that way the browser will not have to wait for the full load.

You could use [django bakery](https://django-bakery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to bake pages into static content served by your webserver